# How to reference an array element as the target for .backgroundImage?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a program that selects images from an array randomly and displays them to the screen. Right now I plan on using an array to store a variety of image urls that can be referenced by a function that selects one of them randomly and uses that value to set the background image of a specific element. For instance:

```
var peach = ["url('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*Gs9AECdBgWc- 
eG5Tjit-EQ.png')", "https://www.wikihow.com/images/thumb/2/2e/69157- 
3.jpg/aid69157-v4-509px-69157-3.jpg", 
"http://www.snoopcode.com/images/javascript/javascript-arrays-main.jpg"];

 function displayImage() {
   document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundImage = 
peach[1];
}

displayImage();
```

This doesn't work though because the syntax for backgroundImage links is ... = "url('link')". Is there a way I can access the array elements to set the background image?

Comment: Why not just add the needed characters to the urls to make them valid values for background-image rule, like you've done in `peach[0]` ..?

Answer (score 1):

you need to concate string like below

```js
var peach = ["https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg", "https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg"];

function displayImage(index) {
console.log("displaying----",peach[index])
  document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + peach[index] + ')';

}

displayImage(0);
```

```css
#body{
height: 149px;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  hello
</div>
```

Comment: I thought of that at first then thought "No, it can't be that easy." Should have just tried it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: hahaha, welcome! please mark this correct if it helped you :)